# Proxy Scraper from Python 2.x to Python 3.x conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-proxy

I was trying to convert a very simple function on Python 2 to Python 3 that would **scrape** a web page and return a list of proxys so I could use on a Twitter robot:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#python25 on windows7
#####################################
# GPL v2
# Author: Arjun Sreedharan
# Email: arjun024@gmail.com
#####################################

import urllib2
import re
import os
import time
import random

def main():
    request = urllib2.Request("http://www.ip-adress.com/proxy_list/")
    # request.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; es-ES; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5")
    #Without Referer header ip-adress.com gives 403 Forbidden
    request.add_header("Referer","https://www.google.co.in/")
    f = urllib2.urlopen(request)

    #outfile = open('outfile.htm','w')
    str1 = f.read()
    #outfile.write(str1)

    # normally DOT matches anycharacter EXCEPT newline. re.DOTALL makes dot 
    include newline
    pattern = re.compile('.*<td>(.*)</td>.*<td>Elite</td>.*', re.DOTALL)
    matched = re.search(pattern,str1)
    print(matched.group(1))
    """
    ip = matched.group(1)
    os.system('echo "http_proxy=http://'+ip+'" > ~/.wgetrc')
    if random.randint(1,2)==1:
        os.system('wget --proxy=on -t 1 --timeout=14 --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; es-ES; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5" http://funnytweets.in -O /dev/null')
    else:
        os.system('wget --proxy=on -t 1 --timeout=14 --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.2.149.29 Safari/525.13" http://funnytweets.in -O /dev/null')
    """
 if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        main()
        time.sleep(2)
```

Ok, I already know that the urllib2 is diferent on P3 but i could not make it work :( Anyone can help? :) thanks!

Comment: Original thread on GitHub https://github.com/arjun024/get-a-random-proxy-address/blob/master/src/getProxyAddress.py

Comment: FYI it’s scrape and scraper not scrap or scrapper

Answer (score 2):

In Python3 `Request` and `urlopen` are located in the `urllib.request` module, so hou have to change your imports accordingly.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
```

You could make your code Python2 and Python3 compatible if you catch `ImportError` exceptions when importing from `urllib2`.

```
try : 
    from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
except ImportError: 
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
```

Also keep in mind that `URLError` and `HTTPError` are located in `urllib.error`, if you need them.